# Call to undefined function apache_request_headers()

Tags: php

I've just switched my scripts to a different server. On the previous server this worked flawlessly, and now that I've switched them to a different server, I can't understand the problem.

I'm not sure it would help, but here's the relevant code.

`$headers = apache_request_headers();`

PHP Version is: PHP 5.3.2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php), before the release of PHP 5.4.0:

> This function is only supported when PHP is installed as an Apache module.

PHP 5.4.0 and later support this function unconditionally.

Said docs also include replacement functions that mimic the functionality of `apache_request_headers` by stepping through `$_SERVER`.

Comment: The [current docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apache.php) still mention that `apache_*()` functions are only available when running PHP as an Apache module. The [specific doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) for `apache_request_headers()` says that it's now (>= 5.4.0) available under FastCGI, but I doubt it's available *unconditionally*, under IIS for example?

Comment: I'm running PHP 7.2.19- on Nginx in ubuntu server and I don't think that "apache_request_headers()" methord is avalable unconditionally. I'm getting same error "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_request_headers()"

Answer (score 66):

You can use the following replacement function:

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('apache_request_headers') ) {
///
function apache_request_headers() {
  $arh = array();
  $rx_http = '/\AHTTP_/';
  foreach($_SERVER as $key => $val) {
    if( preg_match($rx_http, $key) ) {
      $arh_key = preg_replace($rx_http, '', $key);
      $rx_matches = array();
      // do some nasty string manipulations to restore the original letter case
      // this should work in most cases
      $rx_matches = explode('_', $arh_key);
      if( count($rx_matches) > 0 and strlen($arh_key) > 2 ) {
        foreach($rx_matches as $ak_key => $ak_val) $rx_matches[$ak_key] = ucfirst($ak_val);
        $arh_key = implode('-', $rx_matches);
      }
      $arh[$arh_key] = $val;
    }
  }
  return( $arh );
}
///
}
///
?>
```

Source: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

Comment: I've used this function on my site but it seems to run slow, is there any ways to speed it up?

Comment: @Zabs: Yes, you can setup `$arh` as a static variable in this function to make sure it runs only once. [Example](http://pastebin.com/2NGARe49)

Comment: You need to produce first character uppercase, change from:

$rx_matches[$ak_key] = ucfirst($ak_val);

To: 

$rx_matches[$ak_key] = ucfirst(strtolower($ak_val));

Comment: I can't get the Authorization header if this function

Comment: It works like a charm! I've been using **WordPress** and I've put it up in `functions.php`.

Comment: Be aware: This won't catch all header fields, like "Content-Type" or "Content-Length" because they are not prefixed with "HTTP_" in $_SERVER.

Answer (score 23):

if php is installed as an **Apache module**:

```
apache_request_headers()["Authorization"];
```

else, go to **.htaccess** file and add:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

You can then access request headers using any of these:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]; // using super global
```

OR

```
$app->request->headers("Authorization"); // if using PHP Slim
```

Comment: Working fine to get Authorization, Thank you :)

Comment: Needed the .htaccess and the function of @Babatunde Adeyemi. Thx!

Comment: $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] working for me in codeigniter

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276269/613302), I have used the function from the comments in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php#70810), but found that it's suboptimal, hard to read/maintain, and not complete compared to the (non-conforming) casing of some headers.

So because I needed to *really* be able to rely on it, I recoded it to be more obvious and handle more edge-cases better as well – the original code even states *"do some nasty string manipulations to restore the original letter case"* and *"this should work in most cases"*, which doesn't sound nice for something you should be able to depend on.

It's not perfect, but I find that it's more reliable. One thing it lacks is to work on the actual or original headers, as any modifications to `$_SERVER` will be reflected in the output. This can be mitigated by making the result static and running the function as the first thing on every request.

```
<?php
// Drop-in replacement for apache_request_headers() when it's not available
if(!function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
    function apache_request_headers() {

        // Based on: http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xml#perm-headers
        $arrCasedHeaders = array(
            // HTTP
            'Dasl'             => 'DASL',
            'Dav'              => 'DAV',
            'Etag'             => 'ETag',
            'Mime-Version'     => 'MIME-Version',
            'Slug'             => 'SLUG',
            'Te'               => 'TE',
            'Www-Authenticate' => 'WWW-Authenticate',
            // MIME
            'Content-Md5'      => 'Content-MD5',
            'Content-Id'       => 'Content-ID',
            'Content-Features' => 'Content-features',
        );
        $arrHttpHeaders = array();

        foreach($_SERVER as $strKey => $mixValue) {
            if('HTTP_' !== substr($strKey, 0, 5)) {
                continue;
            }

            $strHeaderKey = strtolower(substr($strKey, 5));

            if(0 < substr_count($strHeaderKey, '_')) {
                $arrHeaderKey = explode('_', $strHeaderKey);
                $arrHeaderKey = array_map('ucfirst', $arrHeaderKey);
                $strHeaderKey = implode('-', $arrHeaderKey);
            }
            else {
                $strHeaderKey = ucfirst($strHeaderKey);
            }

            if(array_key_exists($strHeaderKey, $arrCasedHeaders)) {
                $strHeaderKey = $arrCasedHeaders[$strHeaderKey];
            }

            $arrHttpHeaders[$strHeaderKey] = $mixValue;
        }

        return $arrHttpHeaders;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

same thing happened to me when using "apache_request_headers()" so i used this code - works perfectly for me to output all the headers:

```
<?php

    $headers = array();

    foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
        if(strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
            $headers = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))));
            echo $headers." : ". $i[$headers] = $value . "<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

output example:

```
Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
Accept-Language : en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control : max-age=0
Connection : keep-alive
Host : example.com
Referer : https://example.com/
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
```

Comment: I can't get the Authorization header if this function

Comment: Why are you assigning value to $i[$headers] before echoing it?

Comment: it working for me, thanks..i catch with if($i[$headers] == "Authorization"){

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to get headers using PHP in Nginx

```
function getHeaders()
{
    $headers = array();
    foreach ($_SERVER as $k => $v)
        {
            if (substr($k, 0, 5) == "HTTP_")
                {
                    $k = str_replace('_', ' ', substr($k, 5));
                    $k = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower($k)));
                    $headers[$k] = $v;
                }
        }
    return $headers;
}
```

[Source from this page](http://www.rvaidya.com/blog/php/2009/02/25/get-request-headers-sent-by-client-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

If the `apache_request_headers` function is not available in your PHP environment, you can use the following replacement function to obtain HTTP headers:

```php
if (!function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
    function apache_request_headers() {
        $headers = [];

        foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') {
                $formatted_name = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))));
                $headers[$formatted_name] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $headers;
    }
}
```

This function iterates through the `$_SERVER` array, extracts HTTP headers, and formats their names to follow the conventional title case with hyphens. It can be used as a fallback to retrieve HTTP headers in a consistent manner.