# Is there a apache_request_headers alternatve for displaying HTTP Headers

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I'm currently developing an app in a IGB (In-Game-Browser) for an Online MMO. For third party development the browser sends HTTP headers with in game information such as Locations, Item ID's, Items Type ID's, etc,.

It's a small script I've been using to practice with. This script works on my local server and like everyone else who's posted on this issue it does not work on my web server. I have come to the conclusion that this is due to Apache not being installed as a module. I spoke with my hosting provider. They said they could not tell me anything other than I need to find an alternative to "apache_request_headers". I've looked over all the previously posted issues on this topic on this site and I'm unable to see how it all fits together. How to use the examples on here to accomplish my end result. Like this  [question]: [Call to undefined function apache_request_headers()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916232/call-to-undefined-function-apache-request-headers)

My code:

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

My error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_request_headers() in /home/ncgotggb/public_html/ezalternatives.com/index.php on line 2
```

I have been learning as I go this year and it's been self taught and at a fast pace so I'm still newbish to alot of these concepts. At this point tho I have no choice I'm heavily committed and need to complete it. When displaying your answer It would be greatly appreciated if you showed your solution in complete form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27957883/919216

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like your local server is running Apache and your remote server is not, as this function only works with Apache (unless the server is running PHP 5.4.0, then it also works under FastCGI.

On the PHP Manual page for this function, one of the commenters included a replacement function that will be declared only if the built-in one doesn't exist.  I haven't tested this, but I've seen the same function posted elsewhere.

```
if( !function_exists('apache_request_headers') ) {
    function apache_request_headers() {
        $arh = array();
        $rx_http = '/\AHTTP_/';

        foreach($_SERVER as $key => $val) {
            if( preg_match($rx_http, $key) ) {
                $arh_key = preg_replace($rx_http, '', $key);
                $rx_matches = array();
           // do some nasty string manipulations to restore the original letter case
           // this should work in most cases
                $rx_matches = explode('_', $arh_key);

                if( count($rx_matches) > 0 and strlen($arh_key) > 2 ) {
                    foreach($rx_matches as $ak_key => $ak_val) {
                        $rx_matches[$ak_key] = ucfirst($ak_val);
                    }

                    $arh_key = implode('-', $rx_matches);
                }

                $arh[$arh_key] = $val;
            }
        }

        return( $arh );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that my site in ISP Config was set to have PHP as 'Fast-CGI' - changing this to 'MOD-PHP' fixed things nicely.

Comment: Note that [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) is available under FastCGI since PHP 5.4.0