# Php remove catch doesn´t work for me

Tags: php

I have a problem after uploading file but the page still show the previous image. I have to refresh the page 2-3 times to make the page show the correct image (new image).

I tried to add these line to the top og the page:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 08 Nov 2014 05:00:00 GMT");
```

I have also tried to change the date to the past. But still not work.

In the .htaccess i have also put :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

Nothing help, the page still perform the same thing. I have to refresh the page 2-3 times every time i uploaded new image.

What should I do ?

**UPDATE**

Some PHP lines (I have lots more but to be easy to see i just post the important lines)

```
    $photo=$_FILES['photoA']['tmp_name'];
    $photo_name=$_FILES['photoA']['name'];
    $photo_size=$_FILES['photoA']['size'];
    $photo_type=$_FILES['photoA']['type'];

    $uid=$_POST['uid'];

    $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $photo_name)));

    if ($ext == "jpg" or $ext == "jpeg" or $ext=="gif" or $ext=="png") {

        $filename=$uid.".".$ext;
        copy($photo,"myfolder/$filename");
        }

    }
```

///in my index.php (After fetch sql)

```
if ($row['user_img'] !="" ){

    echo"<div id='userimg_cont' style='background-image: url(../myfolder/$row[user_img]);'>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but this is our method to check browser's cache timing of a user's avatar and if the file was modified, we force the browser to revalidate. Else, returns 304 not modified.

```
$request_headers = apache_request_headers();
$avatar = 'path/to/user/avatar';
$last_modified = xx; //last modified time of our avatar file
$last_modified_str = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $last_modified).' UTC';

//Not outdate
if (isset($request_headers['If-Modified-Since']) && strtotime($request_headers['If-Modified-Since']) === $last_modified) {
    header('Last-Modified: '.$last_modified_str, true, 304);

//else, outdated
}else{

    $info = getimagesize($avatar);
    $mime = $info['mime'];

    header('Last-Modified: '.$last_modified_str, true, 200);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=300');
    header('Date: '.gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s e", time()));
    header('Expires: '.gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s e", time()+300));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="avatar-'.$id.'.jpg"');
    readfile($avatar);
}
```

And why `max-age=300`? This is taken from gravatar's caching mechanism. We believe they have their reason to do so :)

**EDIT**

Another way, dummy proof way, is probably using version, as in, every time the user upload the image, you append the path with `?v=some_version_string` to force browser to re-download the file.

One way of doing it is probably using `$the_url_of_the_image.'?v='.filemtime($the_image_path)`.

**EDIT 2**

One thing I have to point is your code is very prone to attack, but this is not the topic here. Anyway, try this:

```
if ($row['user_img'] != ""){
    $fmtime = filemtime("myfolder/$row['user_img']");
    echo "<div id='userimg_cont' style='background-image: url(../myfolder/{$row['user_img']}?v={$fmtime});'>
}
```

I don't know where do you store your images so I assume it's in `"myfolder/$row['user_img']"`.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  After I put this script to my page I got the error message:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_request_headers()

Comment: @PoramatFin Alternative to that function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9276269/534862 (happens if you do not use PHP in Apache). Also, I have added alternative, simpler solution

Comment: I have put the function into the page after the php script above. I still get the same message. I think I give up soon, seem too complicated.

Comment: Why not try the versioning instead ;) It's the easiest way to tell browser "this file is outdated, download again".

Comment: Lionel Chan  I have no idea how to use that version. I´m not expert in php.

I don´t know where to put that line into my script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37784/discussion-between-lionel-chan-and-poramat-fin)

Comment: WOW... fantastic.
Does it have some rules or limit in this last method

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for your own testing purposes, you can use console in google chrome and check the element here:[image]

This will disable cache for you (you do not need to refresh 2-3 times) at any time, when the console is open.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the answer. But this could not be fixed if the client did not have this setting. Does it have other way in order to make it work automatically ?