# How do you make IIS 7 parse a js file also as a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, iis, mime-types

Ultimately I'm trying to get a particularly reliable way set up on my server to detect somebody's browser name and version (for logging, not enabling features), and somebody pointed [this project](https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/WhichBrowser) out.  That being said, they're using an htaccess file with the following contents:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
```

Their readme file said that this was to get the server to also use PHP to parse a certain js file, and that if htaccess is not enabled, you have to find a work-around.

I'm using IIS 7, which uses web.config files, but I don't see an out-of-the-box mime type for PHP on the Internet, so doing something like this doesn't look like it's going to work:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="PHP mime type" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tried using [this suggestion](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/257066-how-to-set-iis-7-to-parse-htm-files-as-php/), which involved adding handler mappings through the IIS GUI, but that didn't seem to pan it either.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by adding a handler mapping to IIS.  All I did was add the handler mapping with `Request path` set to `detect.js` using the `FastCgiModule` and obviously directing the executable path to where `php-cgi.exe` is on my server.  Then php was parsing detect.js fine, the only trouble I ran into whilst trying to get this to work was that the code that created the `WhichBrowser` object was being run before the `detect.js` script was added/loaded to the given test webpage.  To fix this I simply modified the code given [here](https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/WhichBrowser), to this:

```
<script>
(function(){var p=[],w=window,d=document,e=f=0;p.push('ua='+encodeURIComponent(navigator.userAgent));e|=w.ActiveXObject?1:0;e|=w.opera?2:0;e|=w.chrome?4:0;
    e|='getBoxObjectFor' in d || 'mozInnerScreenX' in w?8:0;e|=('WebKitCSSMatrix' in w||'WebKitPoint' in w||'webkitStorageInfo' in w||'webkitURL' in w)?16:0;
    e|=(e&16&&({}.toString).toString().indexOf("\n")===-1)?32:0;p.push('e='+e);f|='sandbox' in d.createElement('iframe')?1:0;f|='WebSocket' in w?2:0;
    f|=w.Worker?4:0;f|=w.applicationCache?8:0;f|=w.history && history.pushState?16:0;f|=d.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen?32:0;f|='FileReader' in w?64:0;
    p.push('f='+f);p.push('r='+Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));p.push('w='+screen.width);p.push('h='+screen.height);var s=d.createElement('script');
    s.src='http://intranet.zachs/media/whichbrowser/detect.js?' + p.join('&');

    s.onreadystatechange= function () {
          if (this.readyState == 'complete') go();
       }
       s.onload= go;
    s.type="text/javascript";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    })();
```

Then in my `go` function i just have:

```
Browsers = new WhichBrowser();
alert("Browser Info: " + Browsers);
```

Comment: `s.onload` doesn't seem to want to fire off.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested this in chrome and firefox and it worked fine for me

Comment: I'm using Firefox.  I tried to add the handler mapping and the code carefully, but there might be something I'm missing.

Comment: Try modifying the `detect.js` and put `echo 'Hello World!'` as the first line in the php part of the code after the `header` calls then go to the `detect.js` page in your browser and see if it prints it.  You should also see the javascript code being echoed on the page. If the echo works than you have successfully set up the handler in IIS, if not than you will see the php code echoed on the page.

Comment: Apparently IIS didn't like one of the function calls in `detect.js` too much, `apache_request_headers()`.  The documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php says that FastCGI supports it now, so maybe we're using something antiquated over here?  Some replacement code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916232/call-to-undefined-function-apache-request-headers/9276269#9276269 fixed that problem though.  After that everything was able to work great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The mimetypes for PHP are:

- text/php
- text/x-php
- application/php
- application/x-php
- application/x-httpd-php
- application/x-httpd-php-source

Where 'application/php' is the most common one I've seen.

You're Web.config XML code seems to work fine when using 'application/php' but you can also creata a mimetype mapping using the IIS manager (see: http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx).