# When exactly is apache_request_headers() available, and when does it fail?

Tags: php

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2916232/759866) related to the [apache_request_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) function. *This question does not go to the bottom of the problem, and I suspect the accepted answer is not perfectly right, as I've commented [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2916232/759866#comment-37840734).*

**Question 1**: on which platforms is `apache_request_headers()` available?

The doc says that from 5.4.0:

> This function became available under FastCGI. Previously, it was supported only when PHP was installed as an Apache module.

By this I understand that it's still not available, and therefore **undefined**, under IIS. Is that true?

**Question 2**: when can `apache_request_headers()` return `FALSE`?

The same doc says that it can "return `FALSE` on failure", but does not define what a failure is. If my understanding of the first question is correct, then it cannot return `FALSE` when the function is unsupported on the current platform, because in that case the function is purely undefined.

Comment: [This source code search](http://lxr.php.net/search?q=&defs=&refs=apache_request_headers&path=&hist=&project=PHP_TRUNK) provides some clues: in PHP-speak, a "SAPI" is how you run PHP - through an Apache module, a FastCGI server, an IIS handler, etc. Looks from that list like as well as directly Apache-targeted SAPIs, the CLI, CGI, Litespeed, and NSAPI SAPIs provide this function in some form. I believe IIS support is provided by [the ISAPI SAPI](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/sapi/isapi/).

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for this insight, I just tested it on IIS and it does have this function as well! However, on Linux CLI, surprisingly the function is undefined (PHP 5.5 in both cases)?

Comment: Ah, I've just realised that's not CLI itself, it's the "CLI server" (the built-in debug web server); makes more sense now I think about it. Not sure where IIS is getting it from though...